# Specify a dead letter queue when creating an SQS queue using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to create a pair of SQS queues using boto3. The first one is a dead letter queue for the second one.

```py
def create_queues(qname):

    # create a fifo queue with a deadletter queue
    dl_queue = sqs.create_queue(
        QueueName=f'{qname}-dead-letter.fifo',
        Attributes={'FifoQueue': "true"}
    )
    dl_arn = dl_queue.attributes['QueueArn']
    print(dl_arn)


    policy = {
      "maxReceiveCount" : '3',
      "deadLetterTargetArn": dl_arn
    }
    policy = json.dumps(policy)

    task_queue = sqs.create_queue(
        QueueName=f'{qname}.fifo',
        Attributes={'RedrivePolicy': policy}
    )

create_queues('test')
```

I can create queues with other attributes just fine, but the `RedrivePolicy` attribute needed to specify the dead letter Queue ARN is a nested attribute, while all the others are simple key value pairs. The [boto docs page](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.create_queue) isn't clear how to handle this nested attribute.

I've tried with both a boto.resource and a boto.client, and several variations of JSON, strings, and Python dictionaries. I've also seen a bunch of related error messages and questions, but haven't found a simple solution (I think setting the attribute afterwards is a workaround, but I'd like to figure out how to set this RedrivePolicy at creation time rather.)

The error message I get for the code above is as follows. I'm not sure if it is complaining about the colons in the ARN or about the quotation marks in the JSON policy.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqshelper.py", line 57, in <module>
    create_test_queue()
  File "sqshelper.py", line 29, in create_test_queue
    queue_url = create_sqs('testbot.fifo', redrive_policy=redrive_policy)
  File "sqshelper.py", line 16, in create_sqs
    response = sqs_client.create_queue(
  File "/Users/g/git/sqstasks/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 395, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/g/git/sqstasks/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 725, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CreateQueue operation: Can only include alphanumeric characters, hyphens, or underscores. 1 to 80 in length
```

Comment: The stack trace doesn't relate to the code you've posted. Also, the maxReceiveCount should be numeric.

Comment: The error message indicates max length of 80 and a restricted character set, both of which suggest that the error relates to the queue name you have provided. That's the only parameter to [CreateQueue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_CreateQueue.html) that seems to have that validation requirement. Gievn that's it's FIFO and you've given it a .fifo suffix, do you also need to indicate FifoQueue:True in the attributes?

Answer (score 0):

As jarmod hinted at in the comment, this was from not specifying the Fifo attribute for the dead letter queue.

The following code works as expected.

```py
import boto3
import json

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

sqs = boto3.resource("sqs", region_name="eu-west-2")


def create_queues(qname):

    # create a fifo queue with a deadletter queue
    dl_queue = sqs.create_queue(
        QueueName=f"{qname}-dead-letter.fifo", Attributes={"FifoQueue": "true"}
    )
    dl_arn = dl_queue.attributes["QueueArn"]

    print("successfully created dead letter queue")
    print(dl_arn)

    policy = {"maxReceiveCount": "3", "deadLetterTargetArn": dl_arn}
    policy = json.dumps(policy)

    task_queue = sqs.create_queue(
        QueueName=f"{qname}.fifo",
        Attributes={"RedrivePolicy": policy, "FifoQueue": "true"},
    )


create_queues("testqueue")
```